# macro with optional argument in eforms textField

Tags: macros, acrotex

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[useui]{eforms}

\newcommand{\myvalue}[1][]{Testvalue #1}

\begin{document}
    \textField[\ui{value={\myvalue[foo]}}]{Text}{2em}{1em}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile it, I get:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\myvalue' on input line 9.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
! Undefined control sequence.
\in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@
                                  ##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...
l.9 ...\ui{value={\myvalue[foo]}}]{Text}{2em}{1em}
```

This even happens if I don't set the optional parameter. The error vanishes when I remove the parameter from the macro or make it a required parameter. Why? And how do I use a macro with an optional parameter here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The value is converted to a PDF string and not typeset by TeX. Therefore the stomach of TeX is not available during the conversion. That means, assignments, definitions, non-expandable macros will not work and can even break. Scanning for the optional argument is implemented via `\futurelet` in LaTeX, an assignment. Therefore `\futurelet` would be written verbatim to the PDF string
as garbage, because PDF viewers do not know TeX commands. And the macro, which should be defined by `\futurelet`, is left undefined, causing trouble at the next expansion steps.

You have already found a workaround, a required parameter instead of the optional argument.